# React reuse a component performing different get/post requests based on where used

Tags: reactjs, native

New to React, creating a website with an api that the front end will get and post data too. I want to have a toolbar for each of the pages, that will offer basic functionality
such as a New, Update, Delete, and Search. Which is easy enough to create, where my question comes in though is this toolbar will be reused on several different pages and i want it to function for the page it is on for that specific element. IE if on the Employee screen it would fetch a list of employees in the system (search), create  an employee (new) or (delete) an employee. But on the Inventory Screen the same toolbar would be used to create (new) inventory, edit existing inventory, etc. 
I can get it talking to the api without issue, but my biggest issue is how do i get it to call the 'api/Employees'... controller methods when it is being used in the Employee section, and how to call 'api/Inventory' methods when used in inventory.

I was grabbing the url path and using the api as a variable such as:

```
var x = 'localhost:xxxx/api/' ;
```

Then appending var x with the url path on so that react would eventually get the full URl of the api to post/get from.

```
var locArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var url = locArray[0];
var x = x + url;
var x is now localhost:xxxx/api/Employees
```

then  further appending the `var` x with the specific method to call (get/post, etc)

and while that works,(not very well as everything has to have the same generic names Employees/Get, Inventory/Get, etc) There has to be a better way to handle it that is more efficient and functional.
Some notes. I use HTMl elements in the react Components themselves, but don't actually use any .html pages, everything is done through React and little bits of jQuery where React gives me too many issues. Using React Router with a switch.

**App.js**

```
  render (){
    return (
      <Router>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/employees"> 
      <ToolBar></ToolBar>
        <SideBar></SideBar>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/inventory">
        <SideBar></SideBar>
        <ToolBar></ToolBar>
        </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

**Toolbar.js**

```
class ToolBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
       ...
      }
      var x = 'localhost:xxxx/api/' ;
      var locArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
      var url = locArray[0];
      x = x + url;
  }

  btnSearchClick(){
      let userToken =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("LoggedToken"));
      var method= "/Get?user=";
      x = x + method;
      fetch('x+userToken, {
        method:'GET'
      }).then((res)=>{
        if(res.ok){
          return res.json();
        }
      }).then((res)=>{
         ... (set state to res.items)
         ... (update LoggedToken, etc)
        }
      });
    }

  render(){
    ...
    <button id="btnSearch" onClick={btnSearchClick} />
  }
}
```

I assume there is some simple step or process i'm missing since the whole point of react is to be reusable I can't image i'd have to have several different toolbars just to accomplish this.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. This is a lot of words. If you just want to re-use a component then give it different parameters (which can include functions, URLs, whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got It working by setting the props on the app page like so

```
 <ToolBar dataSource="localhost:xxxx/api/Employees"></ToolBar>
```

Then doing this in the Toolbar

```
fetch(this.props.dataSource+"/get" ...
```